# angular 2 passing a function var to a different component

Tags: angular

i am new to angular 2 and i have a question.
I created a modal as a component called ModalContent and one of its functions is:

```
@Component({
selector: 'modal-content',
templateUrl: './app/d-modal/d.modal.content.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app/d-modal/d.modal.content.component.css' ],
providers: [InMemoryDataService],
})
export class ModalContent {
    totalSelected:number;

    addM() { 
        let selected = this.m.filter((x) => x["selected"]);
        let totalSelected = selected.length;
        console.log(totalSelected);
        this.activeModal.close('Close click');
    }}
```

How can I pass the variable `totalSelected` in the modal component to a function in a totally  different component called form to use it same as the below:

```
@Component({

 moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'form',
  templateUrl: 'form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'form.component.css' ],
  directives : [ModalContent],`

})`

export class FormComponent {
@ViewChild(ModalContent) childComp: ModalContent;
    addMForm() {
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalContent);
         modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';`
         this.childComp.addM();

    for (var m = 0; m < totalSelected; m++)
    {
        let newGroup = new FormGroup({
          A :new FormControl(),
          B: new FormControl(),
          C: new FormControl(),
          D :new FormControl()
        });



        this.Form.controls.users.push(newGroup);
    }}

}
```

the thing that i want to achieve is to create a number of fields in my form based on the number of selection in the modal component so whatever the user choose in the modal component i want to capture the number in totalselected variable and push it to the form component and use it in the (for) as a counter but it is not working

Comment: is the other component a child component or a parent component?

Comment: you are probably looking at utilizing a service of some sort

Comment: Have you try using Event emitter ?

Answer (score 0):

If the other component is a child component you can use the `@input` decorator to pass data between a parent and a child component. I would look at [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child) it should be helpful. Also, given that totalselected only exists in the scope of the function you provided you may want to return it from the function or create it before the function definition. Also since you have mentioned that your function resides in a modal it might make more sense for you to make the modal a child of the other component and use `@output` decorator.

Edit -- 
You could do something like this

```
totalSelected: number;
addM() { 
let selected = this.m.filter((x) => x["selected"]);
this.totalSelected = selected.length;
console.log(totalSelected);
this.activeModal.close('Close click');
}
```

Now the variable total selected is available outside of the scope of the function call.

Comment: Hello .. i tried input and viewchils but it is still not working . I am not able to use the totalselected from a child component in the parent component . It always tell me that this.childComponent is undefined

Comment: correct that is a scope issue. When you define the variable totalselected inside of the function it is only accessible from the function unless you return that value or define the variable outside of the function. I will make an edit to my answer to show you what I mean. Could you also provide an edit to your question to show how you are performing the input/output variable assignment.

Comment: I added the edited version .. i hope you will find a solution

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution for it?